# how to fetch all values in attributes using magical Records Library Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, core-data

I am using `CoreData` with swift,I am facing an issue in core data while fetching.
I have an Entity with 3 attributes. I am able to save the data Successfully in attributes. only i want to fetch Data from one attribute

[Image for Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zVza.png)

Answer (score -1):

1) Create object of ManagedObject like,

```
var objModel = [NSManagedObject]()
```

then fetch data like,

```
func loadData()
{
    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.managedObjectContext
    let fetchReq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Student") // Your entity
    var fetchResult = [NSManagedObject]()

    let err : NSError! = nil
    do{
        fetchResult = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchReq) as! [NSManagedObject]
        self.objModel = fetchResult
        self.tblList.reloadData()
    }
    catch{
        print(err)
    }

}  // Call this loadData() in ViewDidLoad
```

Then you can get record in CellForRow method of tableview like,

```
self.objModel[indexPath.row].valueForKey("parent_id")
self.objModel[indexPath.row].valueForKey("task_id")
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: hi ,only i want to fetch data in dates Attributes and i am using magical record library

Comment: It is better to store date in String rather then any else type..because it will be easy to handle and once you store it then you can convert it in Date type from the string.